# Loading Rstudio packages in unix/cluster to use in a global rstudio platform

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, netcdf

I am trying to load in specific the package ncdf4 into a global Rstudio platform by running commands on the cluster(unix).

Usually the way to operate is to go for:

```
load module R
load module netcdf
```

although I've tried several versions of the modules, i still cannot access the ncdf4 package using the global Rstudio.

here is a copy of the error text:

```
> library (ncdf4)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/cm/shared/apps/R/3.2.4/lib64/R/library/ncdf4/libs/ncdf4.so':
  libnetcdf.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ncdf4’
```

Any tips in reasoning, procedure or application will be highly appreciated.
I already tried logging in and out from R but it is still not working

Comment: Can you post any error, log or similar?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Done in the post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RNetCDF cannot open shared object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487113/rnetcdf-cannot-open-shared-object-file)